# Auto populate Django ModelForms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I was wondering how to auto populate fields in a form like in this picture http://prntscr.com/lkn7x . Here is what I have so far for my forms.

```
class PIREPForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PIREP
```

Comment: initial={'field': 'value'}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the model form you can pass the instance which will be mapped to the form fields

```
form = TestForm(instance = test_instance)
```

Otherwise, if you want to populate some fields you could pass the initial argument

```
form = TestForm(initial = {'field_name':field_value,...})
```